# Read from bytestream in asp

Tags: asp.net

I'm wondering if it's possible to read from a bytestream without saving it.

I have a file, wich is a PDF that's in a mailbox. Through code I can access this mailbox and read out the attachements in it (the pdf's) At that point every pdf is in a bystream.

For now I just save it locally to test if my code works. But I need to work without saving the file.

Is there a way so I can get data from that file without saving. I need to process the first page and find the image in there (which is a qr code).

I have code to do this from a local file, but I want this to be directly from on of those in the bystreams.

Can I store the bytesteam in something like an object or a list of bytestreams and use that?

Comment: Can you show your current code to read the files? That makes it easier to advise you on what amendments would be needed.

Comment: Try using MemoryStream.

Comment: Basicly there's just a method that creates a list of images, which are extracted from a given pdf. The method receives a file path, and I just use a button in the view to browse the file locally. I'm also using iTextsharp. Had to put the method on pastebin hence it was to long to copy here (http://pastebin.com/cSmYUJS2)